# Seletor lt() não funciona

Tags: jquery, seletores

Nos meus experimentos com seletores jQuery me deparei com algo que não sei se é um erro meu ou é uma limitação natural do jQuery.
Eu tenho 10 divs com as classes `.dado`. Cada uma, ao ser clicada, muda o evento `onclick` de uma outra (única), que tem o id `#download`. 
Apenas as 5 primeiras devem mudar o `onclick` da div `#download`. Tentei usar o seletor lt() para isso, mas vi que não rola. Todas as 10 divs recebem a função.

Como fiz:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dado:lt(5)").click(function(){
    $("#download").attr("onclick", "href('http://meulink.com')");
  });
});
```

Ele realmente não consegue fazer isso, errei algo ou teria uma solução alternativa?

Comment: Não há nada de errado com seu script. Reveja a marcação HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como pode ver no exemplo, o método **:lt()** funciona perfeitamente para o propósito que quer aplicar:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".dado:lt(5)").on("click", function() {
    $("#download").prop("href", "http://meulink.com");
    console.log($(this).text()+" - "+$("#download").prop("href"));
  });
});
```

```css
.dado {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dado">DIV 01</div>
<div class="dado">DIV 02</div>
<div class="dado">DIV 03</div>
<div class="dado">DIV 04</div>
<div class="dado">DIV 05</div>
<div class="dado">DIV 06</div>
<div class="dado">DIV 07</div>
<div class="dado">DIV 08</div>
<div class="dado">DIV 09</div>
<div class="dado">DIV 10</div>
<a href="" id="download">DIV ÚNICA</a>
```

Comment: Ah, agora entendi meu erro! Eu me confundi por ver que clicando na div 6 adiante a div única ainda continuava a ser o mesmo link da 5, daí pensava que era porque elas também a alterava, mas é porque elas não tem nada a alterar para o link mudar...

Comment: Isso mesmo, exatamente. A partir da **sexta** os clicks não fazem mais nada.

Comment: Uma dúvida que tenho é se é possível pegar divs do "meio", exemplo, quero da 3 a 6. Tem um seletor pra isso?

Comment: Cara para te falar a verdade, não conheço nenhum método ou seletor que possa pegar elementos com intervalos, acho que neste caso teria que fazer um for nos elementos mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Use o método jQuery `lt()` combinado com o método `gt()`.

No exemplo a seguir a função será executada para clicks nos `div` 03 a 06 *inclusive* (a contagem Javascript começa em ZERO).

É importante que os métodos sejam aplicados na ordem `:lt():gt()`. Se você inverter a ordem para `gt(1):lt(6)` a função será executada para clicks nos `div` 03 a 08  *inclusive*.

Isso não é um 🐛 "bug"  🐞 da jQuery. Você sabe o porquê?

```js
$(".dado:lt(6):gt(1)" ).click(function(){
  //$("#download").attr("onclick", "href('http://meulink.com')");
  console.log($(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<div class="dado">DIV 01</div>
<div class="dado">DIV 02</div>
<div class="dado">DIV 03</div>
<div class="dado">DIV 04</div>
<div class="dado">DIV 05</div>
<div class="dado">DIV 06</div>
<div class="dado">DIV 07</div>
<div class="dado">DIV 08</div>
<div class="dado">DIV 09</div>
<div class="dado">DIV 10</div>
<a  onclick="" id="download">Link</a>
```